# How to Set Slices in Haskell's HMatrix?

Tags: haskell, matrix, hmatrix

Haskell's `HMatrix` allows you to conveniently ***get*** slices:

```hs
m ?? (All, Take 3)
```

But how can you ***set*** slices, especially non-rectangular ones? For instance, in Python's Numpy I'd do:

```py
>>> x = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
>>> x
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> x[[0,0], [1,3]] += x[[2,2], [1,3]]     # to ix (0, 1) add (2, 1)  and  to ix (0, 3) add (2, 3)
>>> x
array([[ 0, 10,  2, 14],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

I'm able to write this helper function myself, but, it's sure ugly, and partial, and required I add `zipWith3M_` which should exist in the `vector` library but doesn't:

```hs
setSlice :: (Element t, Num t) => Matrix t -> (Extractor, Extractor) -> Vector t -> Matrix t
setSlice parent (Pos (V.map fromIntegral -> irows), Pos (V.map fromIntegral -> icols)) sub = runST $ do
  tparent <- thawMatrix parent
  zipWith3M_ (writeMatrix tparent) irows icols sub
  freezeMatrix tparent
```